# When running my test logging code, I got a window that said "A java exception has occurred"

Tags: java, logging

Beginner here. It also left some debug information behind, but I have no clue what it means.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.log4j.*;  
  
public class Example{  
  
static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class);  
   
   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException
   {  
      Log.debug("Hello this is a debug message");  
      Log.info("Hello this is an info message");  
   }  
}
```

Error message:

```
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:82)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:33)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category$PrivateAdapter.newLogger(Category.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.getInstance(Category.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.getInstance(Category.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.getInstance(Category.java:134)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:41)
    at Example.<clinit>(Example.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 9 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have the slf4j jar on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the dependency. If you're using maven add the following to `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Or if you're using gradle, add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.0'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.0'
}
```